# rails validates : message when it not passed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

With rails we can put message with validates `"format:", "inclusion:" "exclusion:"...`

but how can I write a global message error when validates not passed?

`":message" does't works in validates hash key.`

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If you want to communicate validation errors from your model to your front-end, you need to do that by rendering something in a view.

Comment: I want to add a raise error message, like: format: { with: foo, message: bar }, but I want this message appear if validates not passed, not just for one reason in particular (format, inclusion or other).

Comment: Use 'if: :custom_method'

Comment: @Richlewis how? if is when you want run validation when something, here it's not my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is outside the scope of the `format` validators provided by Rails. To do this, you can [write your own custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) that fits the purpose, or inline a method for validation like so:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :correct_format?

  def correct_format?
    errors.add(:some_attribute, 'Generic message') unless some_attribute =~ /[a-z]/
  end
end
```

Comment: yes but, if I want use "presence" or "format" in same time? :s

Comment: Presence is already validated when you check against a non-empty regular expression. Regardless, you can add however complex a method you would like… including validating multiple conditions.